# Netsuite: Add new value in custom list via REST webservice

Tags: rest, netsuite, suitecloud

I am new to netsuite. I am using Netsuite REST webservice to post my application data to netsuite.
So far I have managed to create customer, add address and get reference to different custom fields internal Ids.

One of the things I want to achieve is to look for a value in "Custom List" and if the value doesn't exist, then create a new value under that Custom List.

I have managed to identify whether the value exist in custom list or not using following endpoint

```
GET /record/v1/<custom_list_id>?q=name IS "<value>"
```

But when I try to call POST on the same endpoint with body `{"name": "<New value>" }` I get following error

```
{
    "type": "https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.1",
    "title": "Pre-processor error occured! Unknown custom record type Error ID: xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "status": 500,
    "o:errorCode": "UNEXPECTED_ERROR"
}
```

I have found some examples of how to create a new Custom Record Type, but none about Custom List.

Comment: I’m trying to do something very similar to you and I wonder if you can share your working code please?